# Age rating for Town of Salem?

Tags: town-of-salem

What is the age rating and/or recommendation for Town of Salem?

I have been playing this game for a while and I kind of enjoy it but when the school staff members see me play it, they also ask if it is game suitable for me. The reason why I'm asking is because it contains death and maybe happened in real life events so I want to show them what is the age suitable for that game.

Is it suitable/safe for ages 13+?

Comment: I checked Common Sense Media, and they don't have it listed. Neither Steam nor the game's website have a rating, so I dunno.

Answer (score 6):

Town of Salem is merely a recreation of the widespreads and well known games like Werewolves or Mafia.

Even though Town of Salem is a computer game (which thus features graphics that are not present in the original card games), the themes are the exact same ones, with the same kind of events and topics, the same player to players type of exchange, etc...

The card games are rated 8+ when sold in shops, and even if there is indeed images and animations depicting death, there is no overuse of violence and blood.

So yes, maybe this would be rated 13+, but I don't see why it would be higher than that considering the original games rating.

Answer (score 0):

It's not abour Town of Salem rating, it's about the issue of it being a video game.

Mafia is commonly played in primary schools, kids just know it, they will make up silly stories and (what they believe to be) gruesome deaths and nobody will bat an eye.

Once you mix in internet/video game, suddenly it catches attention of teachers. For instance, nobody cares what kids sing, but if you ask your teachers to make a cup song video as a whole school, the line including "bottle of whiskey" can be a problem and being a (relatively) young teacher, I have seen that happen. PTA banning Cup Song because it mentions whiskey, but having no problem with Pitbull songs playing at school disco.

I suggest explaining to teachers it is basically Mafia and the level of death in this game is comparable to Grimm Brothers stories.